# How to create random unique (not repeated) and fix length (9 digits) primary key in mysql database?

Tags: mysql, random, server, unique

As the title, how to create a 9 digits number primary key which is random, unique, not repeated and from range 100000000 to 999999999? 
And this method must be work on the godaddy server, seems godaddy have so many limitation.

Comment: godaddy is the unspoken word. You shant speak it (from a Star Trek episode)

Comment: ...Made it so(for the title)...(most Star Trek TNG episodes)

Comment: How about letting MySQL use its own mechanism for primary key and you simply encode the number you got back using [Hashids](http://hashids.org/)? Instead of altering how MySQL works and breaking what hundreds of super-smart developers did, simply work with the output and deliver it in a different format.

Comment: Why do they need to be random? Isn't "unique" enough? An ID's job is to identify the row, not obfuscate its identity.

Comment: @N.B.brilliant idea!! but i also have to use the id for input and that time i have to decode, what mechanism should i use for ur idea?

Comment: @RyanVincent you means we pre-generate a list of unique random id, then when we update the pre-generate record in database?

Comment: You use the library I linked for encoding **and** decoding the input. If user provided properly-encoded value, it will be decoded successfully. Since the library's salt, alphabet and length is configurable, you can receive what you wanted without involving MySQL.

Comment: @N.B.library you linked?

Comment: @chengwei - there's a link in his first comment, next to the library's name...

Comment: @N.B.I found it, thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

I can only think of two reliable ways of creating *unique* numbers.

- Use a systematic process, such as auto-incrementing, where you now the numbers are unique.
- Store generated numbers in a table.

You want random numbers, so the first method *could* be applied using a pseudo-random number generator.  But the second is probably simpler to implement.

It goes something like this:

```
create table numbers (
    numberid int auto_increment primary key,
    n varchar(10) not null unique
);
```

Then you need to create numbers using a loop.  Do the following until it succeeds:

```
insert into numbers (n)
    select cast((rand(*) * 900000000) + 1000000000 as varchar);
```

You can use `last_inserted_id()` to then get the most recent number inserted.

Comment: But what if 2 people insert the number at the same time to database, will it  still unique?

Comment: @chengwei . . . A `unique` constraint is a database guarantee.  If two users attempt to insert the same number, then one of the inserts will fail.

Answer (score 1):

If pseudo-random is OK for you, you could create a trigger like this:

```
create trigger tr_setid before insert on mytable for each row
   set new.id := (
       select mod ((count(*) ^ 42) * 479001599 + 714320596, 900000000)+100000000
       from mytable);
```

This system is not good if you also delete records from your table, as this solution assumes `count(*)` is one larger every time this trigger runs.

The multiplier is a prime and not a divisor of 900000000, guaranteeing that no duplicate number will be generated before all possible numbers have been visited.

The `^` operator is just mapping the `count(*)` so to make the generated series a bit less predictable.

With this trigger the first 10 records in the table will get these `id` values:

```
232387754
711389353
174384556
653386155
348394150
827395749
290390952
769392551
900374962
479376561
```